# How to access Atlassian cloud?

Tags: server, redmine, confluence

I have a huge wiki on redmine and I want to move it to confluence. I found this project https://github.com/vile/redmine2confluence-wiki that would do the job since Atlassian doesn't support this functionality. My problem is that I don't know how to run the script on Confluence server since I am using their cloud. Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The majority of the process should be run on your redmine environment provided it has internet access & has python installed.

The last step cannot be performed for Confluence Cloud

Here's the part (at the end) which confirms this:

> This will result in a script called `fix-author.sql` to be run on the Confluence server.

Being cloud, you don't have access to the underlying Confluence server or the database for that matter.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, do you have any suggestion on how I can move my wiki from redmine to confluence ? @dvdsmpsn

Comment: My only suggestion would be to try out the migration but without the final step.